# How to restrict unwanted logs from Cloudwatch while using AWS Lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I have a lambda function that reads file from S3 bucket and stores it to another S3 bucket. The lambda is working fine, but when I see the cloudwatch for logs, I see additional logs which is not needed.

The additional logs that I get are like below.,

```
[main] DEBUG org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext 
[main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory
[main] DEBUG com.amazonaws.AmazonWebServiceClient
[main] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers
[main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire
```

I want to display only the `logger.info()` used inside the code to be displayed in cloudwatch. Is there any way to restrict those logs from getting displayed ? Can someone provide an example code for reference ?

I am setting log4j.properties file, with the below content.

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO
log4j.appender.A1=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.A1.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.A1.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%t] %-5p %c -  %m%n
# Log all HTTP content (headers, parameters, content, etc)  for
# all requests and responses. Use caution with this since it can
# be very expensive to log such verbose data!
log4j.logger.org.apache.http.wire=INFO
```

Comment: Your Lambda function is clearly written in Java, so you're building a deployment bundle. This bundle includes a logging framework, probably Logback but possibly one of the Log4J versions. You first need to identify that framework, and add the configuration file to your question.

Comment: updated the question @guest

Answer (score 0):

This is a Log4J 1.x logging configuration, so the way to eliminate unwanted messages is:

1. Change the root logger to only allow important messages (you could set it to `OFF`, but you really want to see errors wherever they occur):

   `log4j.rootLogger=ERROR`
2. Change the logger for your application to enable logging:

   `log4j.logger.com.example.myprogram=INFO`

If you have multiple packages that you want to display, you need to set their logging configuration individually.

Comment: For your specific configuration, you'll also need to delete the `org.apache.http.wire` configuration.